# Prepared statement LIKE wildcard

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've made a function that accepts a search column, search term and an id number, and am trying to construct a prepared statement and fetch results, and return in json.

Here is what I have:

```
function searchBooks($searchColumn, $searchTerm, $teacherid) {
    $books = array();

    $link = connect_db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE teacher_id = ? AND ? LIKE ?";
    $searchTerm = "%{$searchTerm}%";

    $stmt = $link->stmt_init();
    $stmt->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('iss', $teacherid, $searchColumn, $searchTerm);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        $book = new Book();
        $book->id = $row['id'];
        $book->title = $row['title'];
        $book->author = $row['author'];
        $book->ar_quiz = $row['ar_quiz'];
        $book->ar_quiz_pts = $row['ar_quiz_pts'];
        $book->book_level = $row['book_level'];
        $book->type = $row['type'];
        $book->teacher_id = $row['teacher_id'];

        array_push($books, $book);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    return json_encode($books);
}
```

I'm using a test page that passes values that I know should return results (using 'the' as a wildcard and 'title' for search column):

```
echo searchBooks('title', 'the', 1);
```

...but I am not getting any results at all... `[]` output on the test page.

Assume `connect_db()` retrieves a connection. Assume I'm doing all my error checking and everything in my controller level, and might add stuff like that later. Just trying to get results right now. Thanks in advance for anything you can point out.

Comment: searchcolumn cannot be a bind variable. You can't bind table/column names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

searchcolumn cannot be a bind variable. You can't bind table/column names

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE teacher_id = ? AND `%s` LIKE ?", $searchColumn);
$searchTerm = "%{$searchTerm}%";

$stmt = $link->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('is', $teacherid, $searchTerm);
```

It would also be a good idea to whitelist `$searchColumn`, validating that it really is a column in your book table before executing this

**EDIT**

And why bother using `fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)` when you're only using associative values from the array? Using `fetch_assoc()` would be better, or you could be even cleverer, and use [fetch_object()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php), and then you wouldn't need to populate your `Book` object property by property

Consider:

```
while ($book = $result->fetch_object('Book')) {
    array_push($books, $book);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `sprintf`? I get `Error: call to undefined function` when using `sprint`.

Comment: @Nathan - yeah, typo, fixed

Comment: Love the suggestions for auto-populating the `Book` object. Just didn't know I could get the fields to align automatically like that. Thanks for the tips, definitely useful.